# Apache Pig Unable to get MIN(column), unexpected symbol

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, min

I am struggling to figure out how to use the MIN() function in this case. I have the following Pig script:

```
A = LOAD '/home/mqp/Documents/p1/data/test_customers.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage (',') AS 

(custid:int, name:chararray, age:int, gender:chararray, country:int, salary:float);
B = LOAD '/home/mqp/Documents/p1/data/test_transactions.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage (',') AS (transid:int, custid:int, ttotal:float, items:int, tdesc:chararray);

C = JOIN B BY custid, A BY custid USING 'replicated';
D = GROUP C BY $1;
DESCRIBE D;

out = FOREACH D {
    allids = FOREACH C GENERATE B::custid;
    singleids = DISTINCT allids;
    
    allnames = FOREACH C GENERATE name;
    singlenames = DISTINCT allnames;

    allsal= FOREACH C GENERATE salary;
    singlesal = DISTINCT allsal;
    
    alltotals = FOREACH C GENERATE B::ttotal as bt;
    mintotals = FOREACH alltotals GENERATE MIN(alltotals.bt);


    transtotal = FOREACH C GENERATE ttotal;
    GENERATE flatten(singleids), flatten(singlenames), flatten(singlesal), COUNT(C), SUM(transtotal), flatten(mintotals);
};

STORE out INTO '/home/mqp/Documents/p1/pig_test' USING CSVExcelStorage();
```

I have tried countless different methods to get the MIN() function here to work to no avail. I have tried grouping by all, using different indices, etc. I am really not understanding what I need to do.

I get errors 'unexpected symbol at or near foo' and 'invalid scalar projection'

Comment: does this script work without use of the MIN function?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `MIN` function in the main `GENERATE` block rather than in the nested `FOREACH` as you currently have it. This is because the MIN function is expecting a bag of values, like `COUNT` and `SUM` which you've used correctly.

Here is a possible version of the script that should work (added some comments for changes I made to your original script for clarity):

```
A = LOAD 'test_customers.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage (',') AS (
    custid:int, 
    name:chararray,
    age:int,
    gender:chararray,
    country:int,
    salary:float
);

B = LOAD 'test_transactions.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage (',') AS (
    transid:int,
    custid:int,
    ttotal:float,
    items:int,
    tdesc:chararray
);

C = JOIN B BY custid, A BY custid USING 'replicated';

-- Removed the DESCRIBE and used field name in GROUP BY for clarity.

D = GROUP C BY B::custid;

out = FOREACH D {
    -- Removed DISTINCT custid 
    -- Because we grouped by this field, we can just generate group
    -- Consider adding name and salary to the GROUP BY if you
    -- expect these to be the same for each custid.
    allnames = FOREACH C GENERATE name;
    singlenames = DISTINCT allnames;

    allsal= FOREACH C GENERATE salary;
    singlesal = DISTINCT allsal;

    alltotals = FOREACH C GENERATE B::ttotal as bt;    
    -- transtotals was effectively the same as alltotals
    GENERATE 
    group,
    FLATTEN(singlenames),
    FLATTEN(singlesal),
    COUNT(C), 
    SUM(alltotals.bt), 
    MIN(alltotals.bt);
}

STORE out INTO 'pig_test' USING CSVExcelStorage();
```